# How to install python modules using cppyy?

Tags: python, meson-build, cppyy

I want to package a python module containing python source and a native c++ library. Cppyy is used to dynamically generate the bindings so the library is really just a normal library. The build system for the library is meson and should not be replaced. The whole thing is in a git repository. I only care about Linux.

My question is how to get from this to “`pip install url_to_package` *builds/installs everything.*” in the least complicated way possible.

What I’ve tried:

- **Extending setuptools with a custom build command**:

  …that executes `meson compile` and copies the result in the right place. But pip install will perform its work in some random split-off temporary directory and I can’t find my C++ sources from there.
- **The Meson python module**:

  …can build my library and install files directly into some python env. Does not work with pip and has very limited functionality.
- **Wheels**:

  …are incredibly confusing and overkill for me. I will likely be the only user of this module. Actually, all I want is to easily use the module in projects that live in different directories…

Along the way, I also came across different CMake solutions, but those are disqualified because of my build system choice. What should I do?

Comment: Did you look into https://pypi.org/project/scikit-build/ already? It's intended for creating extension libraries with custom build tools into a pip installable pacakge. A quick search from there found this [example](https://github.com/ev-br/mc_lib/blob/0ca1bdd5d7f0fd578e5c0613f82fd9fbc2930717/doc/HowToUseMeson.md).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @WimLavrijsen Thanks! As far as I know, scikit-build is cmake-centered. But the example you sent taught me about `mesonpep517` which makes meson visible to pip and solves all my problems! If you post it as an answer, I will mark this question as solved.

Comment: Do you mean something like ```python3 -m pip install --user cppyy``` ?